# chef-server-ctl install I don't know that command

Tags: java, chef-infra

I installed

> chef-server-11.1.7-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

on my redhat 6 machine , most of the chef-server-ctl commands like install, org-list, org-create doesn't work, it shows 
I don't know that command. While the in the help list doesn't show any such command, did i miss something to install or any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You are browsing the documentation of Chef Server 12, however using Chef Server 11. You might want to look at the [documentation for Open Source Chef 11](http://docs.chef.io/release/osc_11-1/) or browse the list of [documentation by release](https://docs.chef.io/releases.html).